# How to calculate the size of enum

Tags: c++, c, enums

```
typedef enum enumStruc_2 {
    ENUM_5 = 0xFFFFFFF0, ENUM_6, ENUM_7, ENUM_8
} enumStruc_2;
```

Here, size of enum is 4 bytes(Integer size). How it saves all of its enum member values within 4 bytes?
Is always enum size 4 bytes irrespective of value of its member?

Comment: There are exactly four distinct sequential values of the `enum`.   To be able to represent all of four distinct values requires no more than two bits.   Since the compiler needs to see the enum to use it, it could easily represent it (in effect) using an `int` as the underlying type.   If the native `int` on your platform is 32-bit, that would explain `sizeof` giving a result of 4.     And, no, the size of enum types are not guaranteed to be 4.   Their sizes are implementation defined - the standard is silent on the subject of what their size should be.

Comment: The question is related to C

Comment: Please don't edit out language tags when there are already answers in place. Yes, this should have been tagged C only, but it its too late to fix once there are C++ answers posted. For cases with both C and C++ tags, please consider the tag moderation guidelines in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).

Answer (score 4):

It's up to the implementation how big an `enum` is.  From section 6.7.2.2p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Enumeration specifiers:

> Each  enumerated  type  shall  be  compatible  with
>   `char` ,  a  signed  integer  type,  or  an unsigned  integer  type.
>   **The  choice  of  type  is  implementation-defined,** but  shall  be
>   capable   of   representing   the   values   of   all   the   members 
>   of   the   enumeration.    The enumerated  type  is  incomplete  until
>   immediately  after  the `}` that  terminates  the  list  of enumerator
>   declarations, and complete thereafter.

So the size of an `enum` type could be the size of an `int`, `char`, or any other integer type.  As an example, [gcc sizes enums](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation) as follows:

> Normally, the type is `unsigned int` if there are no negative values in
>   the enumeration, otherwise `int`. If `-fshort-enums` is specified, then if
>   there are negative values it is the first of `signed char`, `short` and
>   `int` that can represent all the values, otherwise it is the first of
>   `unsigned char`, `unsigned short` and `unsigned int` that can represent all
>   the values.

As for the values of each member, paragraph 3 states:

> The  identifiers  in  an  enumerator  list  are  declared  as 
>   constants  that  have  type `int` and may   appear   wherever   such
>   are   permitted.  **An   enumerator   with
>   `=` defines   its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression.**  If the first enumerator has no
>   `=` , the value of its enumeration constant is 0.  **Each subsequent enumerator with no
>   `=` defines  its  enumeration  constant  as  the  value  of  the  constant  expression  obtained  by adding 1 to the value of the
>   previous enumeration constant.**  (The use of enumerators with
>   `=` may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.)  The enumerators of an enumeration
>   are also known as its members.

In this case, the constant `ENUM_5` is explicitly assigned the value `0xFFFFFFF0`, so  `ENUM_6` is `0xFFFFFFF`, `ENUM_7` is `0xFFFFFFF2`, and `ENUM_8` is `0xFFFFFFF3`.  Each of these constants needs 4 bytes to store the value, so this particular `enum` must be at least 4 bytes in size, although it could be larger.

Regarding:

> How it saves all of its enum member values within 4 bytes?

It doesn't hold all 4 members at once. An enum can hold one of those 4 members. You're defining a type, not a value. For example:

```
enum enumStruc_2 e1 = ENUM_5;
enum enumStruc_2 e2 = ENUM_6;
```

Comment: Why its memory size is not 4*sizeof(int) when it is holding 4 members in it?

Comment: @SurendarSekar It doesn't hold all 4 members at once.  An enum can hold *one of* those 4 members.  You're defining a type, not a value.  For example `enum enumStruc_2 e1 = ENUM_5`.

Comment: @SurendarSekar Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

In both C and C++, the size of an enumerator `sizeof(enumStruc_2)` is the size of any individual element in that enumeration.

In C, the answer is `sizeof(int)`. So that's at least 2.

In C++, the answer is `sizeof(std::underlying_type<enumStruc_2>::type)`.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a type is not the size needed to store all the possible values of that type. It is the size needed to store one instance of that type.

Comment: How it stores 0xFFFFFFF0,0xFFFFFFF1,0xFFFFFFF2,0xFFFFFFF3 these 4 values within 4 bytes?

Comment: Asking "how the enum stores 4 values" is like asking "how `int` stores all its millions of possible values". It doesn't. _One_ integer stores _one_ integer value. If you want to store 40 integer values, you'll need 40 integers. In the same way, _one_ variable of type enum stores _one_ of the possible values of the enum, and it needs to have enough size to do that. Your parking space needs to fit one car, not all the cars you could possibly buy.

Comment: It's also worth noting that "one of the possible values of the enum" is not _only_ the values you listed in the enum's definition. Those are just shortcuts. It can still legally hold any value of its underlying type (e.g. `int`).

Comment: Yes you are right. Is those enum members name replaced with original constant integer value during preprocessing time like #define?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an enum you do two things.  First is you declare a new type that has the name of the enum.  This type is an integer type that is large enough to store the largest value  of the values you use inside the enum and it will not be smaller than an `int` unless you specify so.

The next thing you do is declare 0 or more values of that type that are constants.  These don't participate in the size of the enum like class member variables as they aren't really variables. They are just named constants that you can use and they have the type of the enum type.  This is why you can have as many enum values and the `sizeof(enum_name)` will never change.